# Grep for a range of numbers in R

Tags: r, regex

In R I have a range of numbers between 1002 and 1400 that I wish to match in a column of a dataframe so that I can extract the relevant indices.

So far I have tried:

`grep("1[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]",x$toMatch)`

but this doesn't work since it will also get 1000 and 1001

Is there any way to do this without listing all the numbers?

Comment: You could try `x$toMatch %in% 1002:1400`

Comment: Is this a numeric column, in which case use < and >, or are the numbers embedded in strings, like "I bought 1023 peas"? Please show examples.

Comment: That would work indeed; missed that. However, just for my knowledge, is there also a way to do it via `grep`?

Comment: It's a column of characters

Comment: You could store the result of first `grep` in a vector, and run the second grep searching for 1000 or 1001 with `inverse = TRUE`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `number_range` in `rebus`.  (Make sure you get v0.0-5 or higher; earlier versions had a bug in this function.)

```
library(rebus)
x <- c('blah 1002', '1400 xx', '1234')
(rx <- number_range(1002, 1400))
## <regex> (?:100[2-9]|10[1-9][0-9]|1[1-3][0-9]{2}|1400)
grep(rx, x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this handy web page to make a regex for a range: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

Then, first some sample data that tests the edge cases (note the last example with a number you want embedded in a larger number, just to check that works):

```
> x=paste("X",c(999:1004,1399:1402,99100499),"N")
> x
 [1] "X 999 N"      "X 1000 N"     "X 1001 N"     "X 1002 N"     "X 1003 N"    
 [6] "X 1004 N"     "X 1399 N"     "X 1400 N"     "X 1401 N"     "X 1402 N"    
[11] "X 99100499 N"
```

Then the regex from the site with enough backslashes to keep R happy:

```
> rx="\\b1(0(0[2-9]|[1-9][0-9])|[1-3][0-9]{2}|400)\\b"
```

Giving:

```
> x[grep(rx,x)]
[1] "X 1002 N" "X 1003 N" "X 1004 N" "X 1399 N" "X 1400 N"
```

Add extra test cases until you can break it...

Comment: Nice answer, link is down, though.